# ASP.NET MVC IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, identity-insert

I have the following code in my HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ValidateInput(false)]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")]Article articleToCreate)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View();

            try
            {
                _db.AddToArticleSet(articleToCreate);
                articleToCreate.posted = DateTime.Now;
                _db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

And this is the view for the Create Method

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Create
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div id="create">

        <h2>Create News Article <span>( <%=Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index") %> )</span></h2>

        <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Fields</legend>
                <p>
                    <label for="headline">Headline</label>
                    <%= Html.TextBox("headline") %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="story">Story <span>( HTML Allowed )</span></label>
                    <%= Html.TextArea("story") %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="image">Image URL</label>
                    <%= Html.TextBox("image") %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>

        <% } %>

    </div>
    <!-- END div#create -->

</asp:Content>
```

The problem I get when I try and submit the data is an InnerException saying that the IDENTITY_INSERT is set to off. However the ID in my article table (which is called storyId) is set to Auto Increment, and is also set as Identity and also as primary key/index.

How do I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I will :) Once I get the answer I need I will accept with pleasure.

Comment: If you don't get the answer you 'need', then consider revisiting the questions with some feedback in order to improve the response. I've seen at least two of your questions where someone has provided feedback and you simply haven't responded. Also, if it's any help, your HTML is invalid. An input field in a `p` tag?! Consider using `div`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you create the Linq To SQL DBML file and then change the Database Schema to all for Auto Increment?  I'm thinking that you may have changed the schema but forgot to update the linq designer.

Just delete the table in the designer and re-drag it from the database.

Comment: Genius :) I just refreshed it. Accepted your answer too! ;) Think you could help with this one too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608397/asp-net-mvc-sequence-contains-no-elements/4608420#4608420

Comment: I posted my answer to your other question.